# AngularJS and AJAX injection - Manually start the App?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, wicket

Currently my angular app is dynamically loaded into the current webpage. This means that as well as all scripts (angular.min.js / controllers etc) and  is loaded with the Wicket AJAX request and injected in the current webpage.

The scripts are included in the head, the div injected in some form in the body.

At this point Angular should detect the div and start up the app, but nothing happens. when i try to use console.log(angular) i get angular just like with an normal app. When i try to load the same webpage (without the AJAX injection) the app starts up fine.

How can i manually start AngularJS, or notify to start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap
>
> ### Manual Initialization
>
> If you need to have more control over the initialization process, you can use a manual bootstrapping method instead. Examples of when
>   you'd need to do this include using script loaders or the need to
>   perform an operation before Angular compiles a page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
  <body>
    Hello {{'World'}}!
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
       angular.element(document).ready(function() {
         angular.bootstrap(document);
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*In short:* Remove `ngApp` directive from your html and manually bootstrap

Developer guide has the most you need, I suggest everyone to read it.

Comment: You should call angular.bootstrap when you are done with dynamically loading your page

Comment: No. It is called when the page is ready. But as you said, you are adding some data to your page AFTER the page ready. You should call this when all is done.